# Why does the following axios error occur?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have created a axios setup to get the user details,  everything is working fine, except appending the baseURL in the url, the url "https://localhost:8000/api"

My axios setup,

```
import axios from "axios";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://localhost:8000/api",
});

export const getAllProperties = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get("./residency/allresd", {
      timeout: 10 * 1000,
    });

    if (response.status === 400 || response.status === 500) {
      throw response.data;
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong");
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I got the error when the data is console.log to the console
The error,

```
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
adapter
: 
(2) ['xhr', 'http']
baseURL
: 
"https://localhost:8000/api"
data
: 
undefined
env
: 
Blob
: 
ƒ Blob()
FormData
: 
ƒ FormData()
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Content-Type: null}
maxBodyLength
: 
-1
maxContentLength
: 
-1
method
: 
"get"
timeout
: 
10000
transformRequest
: 
[ƒ]
transformResponse
: 
[ƒ]
transitional
: 
{silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}
url
: 
"./residency/allresd"
validateStatus
: 
ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName
: 
"XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName
: 
"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 10000, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:347565:14)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
constructor
: 
ƒ AxiosError(message, code, config, request, response)
toJSON
: 
ƒ toJSON()
isAxiosError
: 
true
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

The above error was fixed when the baseURL was set to "https://full-stack-real-estate-youtube.vercel.app/api"

How to fix the error having the baseURL as "https://localhost:8000/api"

Comment: try http instead of https so your url becomes``http://localhost:8000/api`` I am guessing you dont have ssl certificates in your local server to make it secure url.

Comment: Removed the dot (.) at the beginning of the URL ("/residency/allresd"). This is because the baseURL is already set to "http://localhost:8000/api", and when making the request, you just need to provide the path relative to that baseURL.